# Unterschiede zwischen „wieder" und „schon wieder"

Tags: difference, adverb

Überall sehe ich sowohl *wieder* als auch *schon wieder* in verschiedenem Kontext, und die Wörterbücher geben dieselben Definitionen und Übersetzungen für beide Redewendungen. Gibt es Unterschiede zwischen diesen?

Zum Beispiel, gibt es eine Bedeutungsnuance zwischen den Folgenden?

> *Ich habe mich entschieden, dieses Buch **wieder** zu lesen.*
>
> *Ich habe mich entschieden, dieses Buch **schon wieder** zu lesen.*

Oder gibt es Situationen, in welchen man nur das eine und nicht das andere verwenden darf?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wiktionary definiert *[schon](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schon)* folgendermaßen:

> zu einem früheren Zeitpunkt als erwartet

Ein Beispiel dort, „Ach, heute schon“ suggeriert die Verwunderung, dass etwas heute bereits ist, obwohl die Erwartung war, dass es erst zu einem späteren Zeitpunkt sein würde.

Wenn ich etwas *wieder* machen muss, so habe ich dies bereits getan und mache es nun erneut. *Schon* drückt darüberhinaus aus, dass die Wiederholung früher eintritt als erwartet oder mir lieb ist.

Das Beispiel aus der anderen Antwort ist sehr gelungen.

> Ich muss schon wieder in den Keller runter, dabei war ich dort erst gerade.

Man hatte nicht vor, zwei mal in den Keller zu laufen, aber da man etwas vergessen hatte, muss man „zu einem früheren Zeitpunkt als erwartet” erneut in den Keller runter.

Answer (score 4):

*wieder* kennzeichnet eine Wiederholung:

> Ich habe das Buch früher schon einmal gelesen. Jetzt lese ich es wieder /
>   noch einmal.

*schon wieder* sagt darüber hinaus, dass wie Wiederholung ungewöhnlich bald passiert:

> Ich war gerade eben erst im Keller. Jetzt muss ich schon wieder
>   hinunter, weil ich etwas vergessen habe.

*Schon wieder* wird vor allem dann verwendet, wenn die Wiederholung oder ihr Zeitpunkt ungewöhnlich ist.

Comment: "ungewöhnlich bald"??? Falls du mit "bald" "häufig" meinst, stimme ich dir zu.

Comment: @EM1 Nein, ich meinte bald: eine ungewöhnlich kurze Zeitspanne seit dem letzten mal.

Comment: Diese Verwendung von "bald" ist mir unbekannt. Auch dein letzter Satz lässt mich stutzen, genau genommen die Aussage, dass der "Zeitpunkt ungewöhnlich ist".

Comment: Ich hab meinen Downvote direkt mal zurückgenommen, da du anscheinend das richtige meinst, ich deine Erklärung nur nicht verstehe. Das was ich da so lese ist meines Erachtens falsch.

Comment: Ich wollte "ungewöhnlich schnell" und "ungewöhnlich früh" vermeiden, da beide Raum für Misinterpretationen lassen. Der letzte Satz möchte sagen, dass entweder die Wiederholung an sich ungewöhnlich ist, oder der Zeitpunkt. (oder beides)

Comment: "...dass eine Wiederholung in relativ kurzer Zeit besonders häufig passiert" — Zwar länger, aber eindeutig.

Comment: Würdest du "bald" denn auch sonst verwenden? "bald" beschreibt zwar die zeitliche Nähe zu einem Event, kann aber imho in dem Satz so nicht verwendet werden.

Comment: Ja, ich würde "bald" so verwenden. "Ungewöhnlich häufig" scheint mir ein bisschen viel, vor allem, wenn es sich gerade um das zweite Eintreten handelt. Inhaltlich natürlich korrekt, aber wirklich gefallen will es mir nicht. Dessen ungeachtet: Deine Einwände habe ich verstanden. Wenn mir eine bessere Formulierung einfällt, werde ich meine Antwort editieren.