# Verwendung von „bald“ um eine „kurze Zeitspanne zum letzten Mal“ auszudrücken

Tags: usage, regional

Ich bin [in einer Antwort zu einer anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/26630/1224) über den folgenden Satz gestolpert:

> *Schon wieder* sagt darüber hinaus, dass die Wiederholung ungewöhnlich bald passiert.

Mir geht’s hier um das Wörtchen *bald*, das mir hier falsch erscheint. Ich verstehe *bald* so, dass etwas in „relativer naher Zukunft passiert“. Beispiel: „Bald ist Weihnachten.“
Die Referenzzeit, wenn nicht näher erläutert, ist dabei immer *jetzt*. Referenziert man einen Zeitpunkt aus der Vergangenheit, so würde man bspw. „Bald danach war Weihnachten“ sagen.

Auf diesem Verständnis basierend, interpretierte ich den Satz oben wie folgt:

> *Schon wieder* besagt, dass eine Wiederholung zu einem Ereignis, das irgendwann in der Vergangenheit war (vor 5 Minuten, gestern, letztes Jahr), in sehr naher Zukunft von *jetzt* ausgehend passieren wird.

In den Kommentaren wurde klar gestellt, was mit *bald* gemeint war:

> eine ungewöhnlich kurze Zeitspanne seit dem letzten mal

Ich würde diese Definition dem Wort *bald* nicht zuordnen. Mir fällt de facto gar kein Wort auf Anhieb ein, ich müsste es mit einer Phrase oder einem Nebensatz näher erläutern.

Nun bestätigte OP aber auch, dass es für ihn eine vollkommen normale Verwendung ist. Und hier kommt meine Frage:

Ist dies eine verbreitete Ansicht? Reduziert sich dies eventuell auf bestimmte Regionen? Ich habe dazu im [Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/) nichts gefunden.
Die Definition im Duden suggeriert diese Bedeutung zwar („nach einem relativ kurzen Zeitraum“), alle gegebenen Beispiele referenzieren aber eindeutig *jetzt* oder einen definierten Zeitpunkt durch bspw. Verwendung eines Adverbs.

---

Es bleibt noch anzumerken, dass der Satz oben absolut OK für mich ist, wenn er wiefolgt lauten würde:

> *Schon wieder* besagt, dass eine Wiederholung bald nach einer zuvorigen Ausführung passiert.

„Nach einer zuvorigen Ausführung“ klingt natürlich nicht schön, man kann es mit Sicherheit besser ausdrücken. Fakt ist aber, dass hier ist eine klare Referenz zu einem bestimmten Zeitpunkt in der Vergangenheit gegeben und eben nicht „seit dem letzten Mal“ impliziert wird.

Comment: Google findet einige Ergebnisse, wenn man nach *ungewähnlich bald* sucht. Ich werte das als Indiz, dass ich mit meinem Sprachgefühl zumindest nicht alleine stehe :-) Ich bin gespannt, was hier heraus kommt!

Comment: @Burki Beachte, dass es mir nicht um die Kollokation "ungewöhnlich + bald" geht. Diese Kombination ist für mich zwar tatsächlich auch ungewohnt, aber nicht von Bedeutung. Es sei denn, dass "ungewöhnlich bald" *die Phrase schlechthin* ist, um "eine kurze Zeitspanne seit dem letzten Mal" auszudrücken. Das dürfte dann aber in den Antworten klar gestellt werden.

Comment: @Burki Auch das stelle ich nicht in Frage. Ich habe selbst ein Beispiel gegeben: "Bald danach war Weihnachten".

Comment: Ich fürchte, dann verstehe ich nicht so richtig... Geht es Dir um "Die Referenzzeit, wenn nicht näher erläutert, ist dabei immer Jetzt." ?

Comment: Bauchgefühl: Regionalismus / Dialekt. Im Schwäbischen kann man sagen: "Du bist heute aber *bald* heimgekommen".

Comment: Nicht nur im Schwäbischen. Wie üblich bei solchen Fragen ist es schwer abzugrenzen (ohne eine große überregionale Umfrage), wo überall _bald_ im Sinne von _frühzeitig_ verwendet wird. Indiz für regional beschränkten Gebrauch dieser Bedeutung ist allerdings, daß der Duden sie nicht aufführt. Er kennt aber die eng verwandte Bedeutung ‘leicht, schnell, rasch’ mit dem Beispiel _etwas sehr bald begriffen haben_ und betrachtet sie offenbar als standardsprachlich.

Comment: @chirlu Da kenne ich noch das Wort "baldig", was vielleicht besser auf die Bedeutungen "leicht, schnell, rasch" passt.

Comment: @Burki Die Antwort von ThorstenDittmar lässt mich glaube ich verstehen, wie du das gemeint hast. Wenn ich jetzt richtig liege, liegt gar nicht das Problem darin, dass wir "bald" unterschiedlich interpretieren, sondern deine Aussage über "schon wieder" anders ist als ich erwartet habe. Um das klar zu machen, ich glaube jetzt, dass du ausdrücken wolltest, dass "schon wieder" ausdrückt, dass die Wiederholung nicht nur früher eintritt als erwartet, sondern der Zeitraum sogar überraschend minimal ist. Sprich, du fokussierst tatsächlich mehr auf die Frequenz (vlg Antwort von falkb), während ich ...

Comment: ...mich eher auf die absolute Häufigkeit beziehe. Also, wenn ich 3x am Tag in den Keller laufen muss um was zu holen, und zwar um 8, um 12 und um 16 Uhr, sage ich beim dritten mal, dass ich "schon wieder" in den Keller geh, auch wenn die Frequenz gering ist. Du betrachtest in deiner Antwort aber eher den Aspekt, dass die Wiederholung 3x innerhalb von 10 Minuten geschieht. — Ist das richtig?

Comment: @Em1 im wesentlichen ja: mein Fokus gilt der Tatsache, dass der zeitliche Abstand zwischen dem vorherigen und dem aktuell gemeinten Ereignis (viel) kürzer ist, als der Sprecher erwartet hätte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Bald* ist hier natürlich aus der Sicht des Sprechers zu sehen, der auch *schon wieder* verwendet. Dadurch definiert sich dann auch der Zeitpunkt, von dem aus eine Sache *bald* geschieht.

Man hätte den Satz auch formulieren können als

> *Schon wieder* sagt darüber hinaus, dass die Wiederholung ungewöhnlich zeitnah passiert.

Auch hier bezieht sich dann *zeitnah* eben auf den Zeitpunkt, an dem ein Sprecher die Formulierung *schon wieder* wählt.

Comment: Hm, interessant. Mit "zeitnah" sehe ich tatsächlich kein Problem. Es ist aber auch kein Synonym zu "bald", obwohl die Wörter natürlich eine deutliche Schnittmenge haben. "Zeitnah" ist eher gleichzusetzen mit "umgehend", "direkt". Eine Wiederholung muss aber nicht sofort passieren, damit man sie als zu früh betrachtet. — Trotz alledem ist deine Antwort insofern hilfreich, dass ich glaube anfangen zu begreifen,  wie "bald" gemeint und zu verstehen ist.

Comment: *Trotz alledem ist deine Antwort insofern hilfreich, dass ich glaube anfangen zu begreifen, wie "bald" gemeint und zu verstehen ist.* Das war mein Plan :-D "Zeitnah" verstehe ich eigentlich auch als "so bald wie möglich", aber es passt, wie ich finde, dennoch im Kontext. Vermutlich (wenn auch holzig) wäre folgendes verständlich: "*Schon wieder* sagt darüber hinaus, dass die Wiederholung ungewöhnlich kurz auf das Originalereignis folgt".

Comment: Also wie sich jetzt herausstellt, lag das Problem gar nicht am Wort "bald", sondern an der leicht unterschiedlichen Auffassung, wie "schon wieder" zu verstehen ist. Für den richtigen Wegweiser gibt's hier den Zuschlag. :)

Comment: Das freut mich, danke! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Ich meinen Augen (und hier ist ja nach der Verbreitung einer Ansicht gefragt) ist „bald“ eine *relative* Angabe eines Zeitpunkts und erfordert also einen eindeutigen Bezugspunkt, der entweder explizit genannt oder aber dem Kontext zu entnehmen sein muss.

Der Bezugspunkt, sofern nicht explizit im gleichen Satz angegeben, muss nicht immer „jetzt“ sein. Mit dem Beispiel

> Bald danach war Weihnachten.

bin ich allerdings nicht ganz glücklich, weil mit „danach“ ja ein eindeutiger Zeitpunkt referenziert wird (der vor dem Satz spezifiziert sein sollte).

Dennoch kann der referenzierte Zeitpunkt auch ohne explizite Benennung im gleichen Satz ein anderer als „jetzt“ sein, etwa in:

> Im Juni 1948 wurde die Deutsche Mark eingeführt. Bald füllten sich die zuvor kahlen Schaufenster wieder mit Waren.

Der Schlüssel zum sofortigen Verständnis des zeitlichen Bezugs liegt in der Nennung eines Zeitpunktes im vorangehenden Satz und der durchgehenden Verwendung des Präteritum.

Im gegebenen Satz

> *Schon wieder* sagt darüber hinaus, dass die Wiederholung ungewöhnlich bald passiert.

ist der Bezugspunkt jedoch nicht eindeutig. Ohne explizite Angabe gehe ich aufgrund des verwendeten Präsens zunächst von „jetzt“ aus, erst bei zusätzlichem Nachdenken über die Semantik eröffnet sich mir die Alternative, dass der Zeitpunkt des vorangegangenen Auftretens des sich wiederholenden Ereignisses gemeint sein könnte.
Um dieses „geistige Stolpern“ zu vermeiden, sollte der Bezug m.E. mitgeliefert werden.

Insofern stimme ich der Auffassung von Em1 größtenteils zu.
Nichtsdestoweniger habe ich in süddeutschen Gefilden auch schon „bald“ im Sinne von „schnell“ oder „früh“ (?) verwendet gehört (was sich mit dem  Kommentar von Stephie deckt). Insofern mag der obige Satz für andere Hörer/Leser akzeptabler sein.

Comment: Ich gebe zu, ich war im einleitenden Teil ein wenig oberflächlich was die Bestimmung des referenzierten Zeitpunktes angeht, wollte mich aber auch möglichst kurz halten. Deine Anmerkungen diesbezüglich sind vollkommen richtig. Danke für die Klarstellungen dazu und ein +1. Jetzt bin ich mal gespannt, ob es noch Gegenmeinungen dazu gibt und welche Sprache Kommentare und Votes sprechen werden. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Werfen wir einen Blick in die Vergangenheit.

[Ludwig Tieck, 1773-1850](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Tieck), (unbekannt durch das Stück „Der gestiefelte Kater“) [Siegfried der Drachentöter](https://books.google.de/books?id=JbwSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA383&dq=%22bald%20zog%20er%20sie%20an%20Haaren%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBWoVChMI2t-Jx9mYyQIVwnkPCh3nyAgm#v=onepage&q=%22bald%20zog%20er%20sie%20an%20Haaren%22&f=false), Romanze:

> (...)
>    Der Meister lehrt ihm schmieden,
>    Siegfried war wohlgemut,
>    Er schlug all die Gesellen
>    In Lust und Übermut.
>
> Sie fürchteten ihn alle,
>    Er brachte ihnen Not.
>    Bald zog er sie an Haaren,
>    Bald droht er ihnen Tod,
>    (...)

Nun handelt es sich einerseits um Lyrik, und in der Lyrik ist vieles erlaubt, was hart an der Grenze ist und darüber hinaus, andererseits ist es uralt und beweist daher wenig.

Allerdings kann vermutet werden, dass ein solcher, für uns ungewöhnlicher Sprachgebrauch, in mehreren, historischen Stücken und Gedichten gepflegt wurde und daher heute nicht unbekannt ist, sondern verstanden wird und womöglich in verschiedenen Floskeln fortlebt.

Schauen wir uns die *bald* an, so ist kein klarer Zeitpunkt auszumachen, auf den sie sich beziehen könnten. Es scheint einfach nur *oft* zu heißen.

100 Jahre später schreibt Theodor W. Adorno:

> Stereotyp jedoch greift Halbbildung in ihrer Angst nach der ihr
>   jeweils eigenen Formel, um bald das geschehene Unheil zu begründen,
>   bald die Katastrophe, zuweilen als Regeneration verkleidet,
>   vorherzusagen.

(Horkheimer, Adorno: Dialektik d. Aufklärung)

Auch hier steht *bald* nicht für ein singuläres Ereignis, welches kurz nach einem definierten anderen stattfindet, sondern für das immer wiederkehrende, das wiederholte.

Comment: Und was möchtest Du uns damit sagen?

Comment: Nur ist es leider so, dass im damaligen Sprachgebrauch *bald* im Sinne von *mal* verwendet wurde. So auch hier: *Mal* zog er sie an den Haaren, *mal* droht er ihnen Tod. Das hat hier keinen zeitlichen Bezug oder die Konnotation von Geschwindigkeit, sondern ist einfach eine alte Form von *mal dies, mal das*.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Das hat was für sich, aber ich meine das 'bald' geht im 'mal' nicht ganz auf, es hat einen Hang zum 'oft'. Es ist mehr ein *'mehrmals dies, mehrmals das'.

Comment: @userunknown dwds definiert: *bald ... bald ... bezeichnet die abwechselnde und schnelle Aufeinanderfolge  bald/balde weint, bald/balde lacht sie*. http://www.dwds.de/cache/shortcuts/bald.html